# How to build a query on laravel correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I am grateful in advance for any answer!

there are CATEGORIES

- CATEGORIES (one) `1⟶n` PRODUCTS (many)
- PRODUCTS (many) `m⟶n` STORE (one)
- STORES (one) `1⟶n` ADDRESS_CITY (many)

CATEGORIES → PRODUCTS → STORES → ADDRESS_CITY

**you must select all the CATEGORIES that have:**

- there is at least 1 PRODUCT / / has
- this PRODUCT must have a STORE in which the ADDRESS exists in California

I tried to build a query, it does not work, there is only the `hasManyThrough` method in the documentation
that jumps through 1 table, and there are more of them here. Or I'm even being stupid)
Help to build a query!

Another question: if I have 1 million products and 1000 stores, will the request be processed normally or do I need to look for other FEATURES:

- save the `id_city` in JSON in the PRODUCTS
- save the `id_city` in JSON in the STORE

Comment: What have you tried so far ? wich problems did you encounter in your tries ? Keep your post about only one question.

Comment: @N69S it is not possible to link all the tables through hasManyThrough, is there another way?

Comment: You dont need to make complicated relation to condition any of those entities with any other entity. Just conventional relations work perfectly `belongTo`, `hasMany` only

Comment: You can do it with nested `whereHas()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @N69S please tell me if it is possible to put has() in ->whereHas ('product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = Category::where('on_off', 1)
    ->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($city_one) {
        $query->where('on_off', 1)

            ->whereHas('shop', function ($query) use ($city_one) {
                $query->where('on_off', 1)

                    ->whereHas('shop_map_point', function ($query) use ($city_one) {
                        $query->where('city_id', $city_one->id);
                    });
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: you dont need the `has('product')`. Doesnt this query work for you ?